# How to set a selectfield in Sencha Touch from array?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch app and I would like to push in a combobox, values previously filtered from a store.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Surveys');
var templatesAvailable = [];
store.filterBy(function (record) {
  console.log(record.get('templateName'));
  record.get('templateName'); --> I get value
  templatesAvailable.push(record.get('templateName')); --> into the array
});
```

Next step would be transfer array to a specified selector, for example and in my case...

`this.getTemplateSelector`

```
  {
    xtype       : 'selectfield',
    itemId      : 'selectSurveysTemplates',
    cls         : 'filterbar-selectfieldplus',
    displayField: 'value',  --> here is the secret  ;-)
    valueField  : 'id',
    autoCreate  : true
  },
```

What should it be the correct way for this implementation?  I have tested with different options but It is not working for me..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Since Sencha Touch does not have an `xtype:'combobox'`, am I right that you want to use an `xtype:'selectfield'`?

Comment: I have edited title of the post.. of course I am using "selectfield" ..thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
selectfield.setOptions(
    store.getRange().map(function(record) {
        return {
            text:record.get("templateName"),
            value:record.get("templateName")
        };
    })
);
```

This should do the following:

- [`Selectfield.setOptions`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-method-setOptions) sets the value of [`Selectfield.options`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-options). According to the docs, `options` takes an array of objects with properties `text` and `value`, so I guess `setOptions` takes the same.
- [`Store.getRange`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) gives you an array of records.
- [`Array.map`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Array-method-map) that takes a function and converts every item in the input array using that function.

Voilà, you should be done.

Comment: debugging `record.get("templateName") is showing the correct value, and in the selectfield I see the length of the array, separated by lines in this case 5, but I don´t see values..  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @inane You didn't provide the definition of your `selectfield`, so it's only a guess: You could have defined a non-standard [`displayField`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-displayField), for instance.

Comment: Well, for `displayField: 'templateName', valueField  : 'id',`, you would have to switch to `return { templateName: record.get("templateName"), id:record.get("id") }` or similar...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alexander  :-D